# How to count actions per individual in the same table?

Tags: mysql, group-by, concatenation

Mysql Table:

(User, action)

what is the query that I can run to get this result

User | count action1 per user | count action2 per user | count action3 per user

Comment: In the result table we want to see only 3 specific action.
Example of a row: User1    5      14       9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user, count(action1), count(action2),count(action3) GROUP BY user
```

You can just group by the user and return a count of records per action.  It's possible you may need to use a case statement in your counts, if you have an `action type` column.  That would look something like this:

```
SELECT user, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN actiontype=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Action1Total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN actiontype=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Action2Total,
       SUM(CASE WHEN actiontype=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Action3Total
GROUP BY user
```

You can also use `COUNT` instead. Because default `CASE` is null, and `COUNT` doesnt count `null`

```
 COUNT(CASE WHEN actiontype=1 THEN 1 END) as Action1Total
```

Comment: I tried to run this query, but I get an error:
SELECT user_id, SUM(CASE WHEN action="DELETE" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Action1Total, SUM(CASE WHEN action="CREATE" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Action2Total,SUM(CASE WHEN action="Finish" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Action3Total) from tbl_audit_trail GROUP BY user_id

Comment: @devlincarnate there was one aditional `)` at `action3total`, try now